# get CtClass using specific ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, javassist, bytecode-manipulation, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a class structure like this:

```java
package com.mydomain.myproject;
public class Outer{
    public class Inner{
        //some code
    }
}
```

Now, I can get a `CtClass` of the inner class using:

```java
ClassPool pool=ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass innerCt=pool.getCtClass("com.mydomain.myproject.Outer$Inner");
```

The problem occurs if those classes are loaded by a special `ClassLoader`.

`ClassPool#getCtClass` fails because the `ClassLoader` it uses doesn't know of the class.

I get the following exception:

```
javassist.NotFoundException: com.mydomain.myproject.Outer$Inner
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:430)
    at javassist.ClassPool.getCtClass(ClassPool.java:495)
    at <my classes>
```

How can I specify the `ClassLoader` for `ClassPool#getCtClass`? Can I somehow set the class loader of the `ClassPool`? I noticed that there is a `getClassLoader()` method but there doesn't seem to be a setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClassPool](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/ClassPool.html) supports inserting, appending and removing [ClassPath](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/ClassPath.html)s.
The ClassPath can be inserted and added in the form of a String or a ClassPath implementation. Removals are only supported in the form of a ClassPath.

There are 4 supplied implementations of ClassPath:

1. ByteArrayClassPath: Supply the byte code and class name
2. ClassClassPath: Supply the Java class
3. LoaderClassPath: Supply a classloader
4. URLClassPath: Supply a URL