# Javassist factory - setting a custom classloader

Tags: java, javassist, cglib

With `CGLIB` I can do

```
final var enhancer = new Enhancer();
enhancer.setUseCache(false);
enhancer.setSuperclass(superClazz);
enhancer.setCallback(...);
enhancer.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());   // This
```

However with `Javassist` I can't find a way to set the `ClassLoader`. Any idea?

EDIT: omg, should I just subclass `ProxyFactory`? That's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Kotlin
ProxyFactory.classLoaderProvider = ProxyFactory.ClassLoaderProvider { javaClass.classLoader }
```

This doesn't seem safe imho. But that's how it's done apparently, per documentation.
Alternatively, just subclass `ProxyFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the classloader by adding ClassPaths to the CtClass.
See answer to question: [get CtClass using specific ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789950/get-ctclass-using-specific-classloader/60792151#60792151)